# Angular Material - How to set properly Angular Material specific dashboard grid?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have a problem with set proper Angular Material grid for specific dashboard. I need to help to set proper margins/padding etc. to view it more compact. Here is simple draw to show what I need:
[Example view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2CuB.png)

Here is description:

- navbar must be full width with margins same as on dasboards,
- under navbar I need to view name,
- tiles must have same dimensions,
- space between tiles must be the same (a, b values on example) - horizontal and vertical margin must be the same a=b

I don't know how to set it properly and can't find solution.
Thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a toolbar, use mat-toolbar, and just add text

If you want to create a grid, where a=b, then define gutterSize, it'll be equivalent

in component.html

```
<mat-toolbar>Dashboard</mat-toolbar>
<mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="100px" [gutterSize]="5">
  <mat-grid-tile
    *ngFor="let tile of tiles"
    [colspan]="tile.colSpace"
    [rowspan]="tile.rowSpace"
    [style.background]="tile.color">
    {{tile.text}}
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

You'll need to create a list of tiles, and define number of rows and columns each tile will take

In component.ts

```
  tiles = [
    {text: 'One', rowSpace: 1, colSpace: 1,color: 'lightblue'},
    {text: 'Two', rowSpace: 1, colSpace: 1, color: 'lightgreen'},
    {text: 'Three', rowSpace: 1, colSpace: 1,color: 'lightpink'},
    {text: 'Four',  rowSpace: 1, colSpace: 1,color: '#DDBDF1'},
    {text: 'Five',  rowSpace: 1, colSpace: 1,color: '#DDBDF1'},
    {text: 'Six',  rowSpace: 1, colSpace: 1,color: '#DDBDF1'},
  ];
```

Alternatively, you could also specify, you always expect 6 columns, and you want x to take up third of number of coulms, to 6/3 = 2 => colspan = 2, and you want y to be half of x, rowspan = 1

```
<mat-toolbar>Dashboard</mat-toolbar>
<mat-grid-list cols="6" rowHeight="100px" [gutterSize]="5">
  <mat-grid-tile
    *ngFor="let tile of tiles"
    [colspan]="2"
    [rowspan]="1"
    [style.background]="tile.color">
    {{tile.text}}
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

You can also choose to either declare all same color, or assign each one different color.

Comment: `mat-grid-list` only works with simple objects such as strings. Trying to use it with random child elements does not work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51801371/191246